# Orient DB - Document and Cluster Mapping

Tags: java, database, orientdb

I am using Orient DB Document model. My code to save a document-

```
private ODocument saveDocument(ODocument document) {
        ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(database);
        return document.save();
    }
```

We create classes from some types and some Document classes are created at runtime hence schemeless.

The save code works fine when the ODocument is of a class that has been defined in a schema. Example we have a Status schema-

```
schema.createClass("Status");
```

So if i do

```
document = new ODocument("Status");
save(document)
```

then the above code works fine.

But if i do

```
doument = new ODocument("RawData");
save(document)
```

then i get `OSchemaException` -

```
Record saved into cluster collectionfile should be saved with class CollectionFile but saved with class RawData
```

Where CollectionFile is some other Schema that i have in my database. My question is that why is Orient trying to save RawData document in some other cluster.

P.S : This code was working fine one day back when i had single DB in my application. Then i changed to a multi DB approach where i have two DB instances in my application.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: which version of OrientDB are you using? from my (quite extensive) experience it's probably a bug on their side...

Comment: 1.7.6 version is the one i am using

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk : thanks!! moving to 2.0.6 made it work

Answer (score 0):

You should set the current db you want to use in case of multiple dbs, with:

```
ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set( database2 );
```

Look at: http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/Java-Multi-Threading.html

Comment: I had done that but it was not working..however moving to orient 2.0.6 made the problem go away :) not sure why 1.7.6 was not working with the same code.